# Display array items on a div element on click of button using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

Can any one please tell me how can print the elements array on a div element

```
var myArray=["stone","paper","scissors"]


<button onclick="printnumbers()"></button>
<div id="result">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do `forEach` over your array `myArray` and append text inside div.

```js
var myArray=["stone","paper","scissors"]
function printnumbers(){
   myArray.forEach(function(el){
     document.getElementById('result').innerHTML+='<br>' +el;
   })
}
// alternative way , suited for your use case.
//var arrayContents = myArray.toString();
//document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = arrayContents;
```

```html
<button onclick="printnumbers()" >click me</button>
<div id="result">

</div>
```

The `toString()` method returns a string with all the array values, separated by commas you can use this method also.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var myArray = ["stone", "paper", "scissors"]
function printnumbers() {
  document.querySelector('#result').textContent = myArray.join(', ');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="printnumbers()">Print Numbers</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.toString()` method.

```js
function printnumbers(){
var myArray=["stone","paper","scissors"]
var display = myArray.toString();
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = display;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="printnumbers()">Display</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray=["stone","paper","scissors"]

printNumbers = () => {
   document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = myArray.join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**With Vanilla.js only, this should help you :)**

```js
const myArray = ["stone", "paper", "scissors"];

const el = document.getElementById('myButton');

el.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const div = document.getElementById("result");
  myArray.forEach((currentValue, index, array) => {
    let text = index == (array.length - 1) ? `${currentValue}` : `${currentValue}, `;
    let content = document.createTextNode(text);
    div.appendChild(content)
  });
}, false);
```

```css
#result{
  width: 20rem;
  height: 1rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  border-width:3px;
  border-style:dashed;
  border-color:#FFAC55;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <button id="myButton">Try it</button>
    <div id="result"></div>

</body>

</html>
```